# Trouble constructing $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If I have $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^2+2x+2)$, I can construct a field by letting $x^2=x+1$. The reps are:

$0$

$1$

$x$

$x^2=x+1$

$x^3=x^2+x=x+1+x=2x+1$

$x^4=2x^2+x=2x+2+x=2$

$x^5=2x$

$x^6=2x^2=2x+2$

$x^7=2x^2+2x=2x+2+2x=x+2$

---

However, when I try this for $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^2+1)$, letting $x^2=-1=2$, it does not work. $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3$ and thus we know $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field.

Here's what I get

$0$

$1$

$x$

$x^2=2$

$x^3=2x$

$x^4=2x^2=4=1$

Why doesn't this work with $x^2+1$?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the issue is that there's no guarantee that $x$ will be a multiplicative generator for the group of units for the resulting field.  You might to choose another element.  One choice might be $x+2$, which squares to $x^2+4x+4 \equiv x$.

Comment: Why would $x^2=x+1$ work but not $x^2=2$?

Comment: There's not really a deep reason behind it...

Comment: Could it be because in the latter case, $x^2 =$ constant?

Comment: @AlJebr Note specifically that $x^2 = 2$ implies $x^4 = 4 = 1$, so you can see immediately that the powers of $x$ will have only $4$ possible values.

Comment: @RolfHoyer I see...In regards to your answer, I don't think letting $x^2=x+2$ will work. We will have $x^2-x-2=x^2+2x+1$ which is not irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: @AlJebr I am instead saying $x = (x+2)^2$, which simplifies to $x^2+1$, which was the given irreducible.